# R markdown show markdown output in .Rmd

Tags: r-markdown

I remember there was a time that when you type # in R markdown it will immediately transfer to the heading output. Also, when you type `**bold**` it will immediately show the text in bold. But now I can't find a way to do this.

Is it possible to show the markdown output in the .rmd document? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour will depend on the text editor you use. Some Markdown editors have a "What You See Is What You Get" (or WYSIWYG) philosophy that will do exactly what you describe. You can find examples of WYSIWYG Markdown editors online, I personally have only tried Typora. But as far as I can tell, none of them seem to support Rmarkdown (perhaps someone has made an Rstudio add-in?).

On the other hand, in the early days of `knitr`, it used to support Lyx (I don't know if it still does), which is maybe closer to what you have in mind? See this post for an example: https://yihui.org/knitr/demo/lyx/